# A Question of Latex Layouting Using \vspace{\fill} and Multi Columned Page

Tags: positioning, multicol

This question is related to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224289/latex-layouting). Read that question, and read the first and the only answer, and its comments.

Answer I got was worked well. But there is a very little problem. Let's say that we have multi columned document:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newenvironment{mybox}{\par\noindent%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
   {\end{minipage}\par\vfill}
\begin{document}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox} \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

The output is:
[image: output]

As you may notice, the last asterisks do not share same horizontal level. The thing I expected was asterisks on the left column should be on more higher level. Because `\vspace{\fill}` should also work at the end of that column too. But somehow it doesn't. So could you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the page break to happen *after* the `\vfill` otherwise it will happen before the `\vfill` on the first column (and so be discarded) but still be there on the last:  so use `\vspace*`

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand\myskip{}  % vertical spacing between mybox environments
\newenvironment{mybox}{\par\noindent%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
   {\end{minipage}\par\vspace*{\fill}\pagebreak[0]}


\begin{document}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
        \begin{mybox}
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{3cm}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox} \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}
    \begin{mybox}
        ++++++\\
        \vspace{3cm}\\
        **********
    \end{mybox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good answer. But if I use `\vspace` instead of `\vspace*`, nothing changes. After I defined the page break positions, why do I still need to use `\vspace*`?

Comment: @jnbrq You need to prevent the page break happening before the \vspace{\fill] which would cause it to be discarded. Alternatively and possibly better, go back to \vspace (or just \vfill but ensure that you do not add a space after the last one, only _between_ your boxes.

Comment: How can I use your solution with `multicols`? I use starred version of multicols environment, but it looks like `pagebreak[0]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this fix is universal, but it works for a number of different box sizes (`\mysize`).  I apply an optional argument to your `\mybox` environment.  If the optional 1-letter argument is `F` or is omitted, it applies a closing `\vfill` to the environment.  For any other letter, it applies a `\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}` (and I am not sure why this works).

Typically, you would apply the optional argument to the last block on a filled page, though not if it was the last block on an unfilled page.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand\myskip{}  % vertical spacing between mybox environments
\newenvironment{mybox}[1][F]{\par\noindent\gdef\applyvfill{#1}%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
   {\end{minipage}\par\if F\applyvfill\vfill\else\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}\fi}
\def\mysize{3cm}
\newcommand\domybox[1][F]{%
        \begin{mybox}[#1]
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{\mysize}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
}
\begin{document}
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox[x]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is the result when `\mysize` is `4cm` and 6 invocations (the last one with `[x]`):

[image]

and then this, with `\mysize` set to 1.5cm and 14 invocations (the last one with `[x]`)

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\newcommand\myskip{}  % vertical spacing between mybox environments
\newenvironment{mybox}[1][F]{\par\noindent\gdef\applyvfill{#1}%
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}}
   {\end{minipage}\par\if F\applyvfill\vfill\else\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}\fi}
\newcommand\domybox[1][F]{%
        \begin{mybox}[#1]
            ++++++\\
            \vspace{\mysize}\\
            **********
        \end{mybox}
}
\begin{document}
\def\mysize{1.5cm}
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox
\domybox[x]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This answer is not generalized enough. But I am curious. Could you explain why did you use `-.5\baselineskip` for the last box? (Even you told you aren't sure, I want to know your idea)

Comment: @jnbrq When a page ended on a box with your original code, there seemed to be a extra blank line at the bottom of the right column.  I thought subtracting it off with a `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` might work, but it removed too much space.  So I set it to `-.5\baselineskip` without any logical rationale, and it seemed to work.